# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: запятая

которая объединяет всё (,) что контрастно.

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, нужна, ведь после слова "всё" начинается придаточное предложение

Comment: Спасибо, Виктор.

Comment: Вы можете принять ответ, кликнув на поднятый палец вверху слева

Answer (score 1):

Нужна. Предложение сложное, союзное, СПП. Первая основа - "которая объединяет", вторая -  "что контрастно" или "контрастно" (надо по контексту смотреть)

Comment: Спасибо, Злата.